# put address->int mapping values in array on geth command line

Tags: go-ethereum, testrpc, mapping

What is Gethian for "append this value to a list".

Given this example contract:

pragma solidity ^0.4.6;
contract MapTester {

```
mapping(address => int256) public addressIntMap;


function Lookup(address input)constant returns(int256){
    return addressIntMap[input];
}
function PutInMap(int256 input){
    addressIntMap[msg.sender]=input;
}
```

}

Which compiles to:

```
var maptesterContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"addressIntMap","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"int256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"input","type":"address"}],"name":"Lookup","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"int256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"input","type":"int256"}],"name":"PutInMap","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]);
var maptester = maptesterContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

make a `testrpc` testnet:

```
testrpc -a 10
```

connect a geth console

```
rpc:http://localhost:8545
```

Put values in the map:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    console.log(maptester.Lookup(eth.accounts[x],{from:eth.accounts[x],gas:3000000}))
}
```

Read the values back:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    maptester.PutInMap(x,{from:eth.accounts[x],gas:3000000})
}
```

Gives:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
undefined
>
```

**How might I get the above in list or array format (or similarly printed text)?**

Comment: For future reference, it's not "Gethian" it's just JavaScript, so you can always google "put values in array JS" or something of the sort

Comment: @TjadenHess thanks yes, for some reason I'd thought there was more to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed ['push'](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp):

```
var li = []

for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    li.push(maptester.Lookup(eth.accounts[x],{from:eth.accounts[x],gas:3000000}))
}
```